# How do I exclude custom Info.plist values from Release build?

Tags: swift, xcode

I added a few custom values into Info tab in Xcode which forced the app to create a file named Info.plist in my project. These values are in the Info.plist file AND in the Info tab which is confusing, because I can delete the Info.plist file and the values remain. However I need to exclude them from release builds, how can I do it?

```xml
<dict>
    <key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Access to the local network for development builds</string>
    <key>NSBonjourServices</key>
    <array>
        <string>_nslogger._tcp</string>
        <string>_nslogger-ssl._tcp</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: I had thought the Xcode UI would let you do this in the target's "Info" tab, but it appears that you need to use variables (like `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`, and then use the existing build configuration system to set the values for each build type. 

Try -> https://sarunw.com/posts/set-info-plist-value-per-build-configuration/ ?

Answer (score 0):

So @benc was right, I was following idea mentioned here: [https://sarunw.com/posts/set-info-plist-value-per-build-configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFPbd.jpg)

Solution which works correctly is on following screenshots.
[image: Info.plist]

[image: User-Defined setttings]